# Javascript swaps to mm/dd date but the input field is dd/mm

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, date

I have an html form with bootstrap with this date fields:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="from" name="from" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="to" name="to" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

I need to compare the two to check "to" is a date after "from", but when I compare using this code:

```
if(new Date($("#from").val() > new Date($("#to").val()) ....
```

the calculation goes wrong because under the hood it swaps month numbers with the day numbers. How do I force it to take the dd/mm/yyyy format (or convert the input as mm/dd/yyyy) to get the proper calculation?
Thank you.

Comment: Cant see elements with ids 'dal' and 'al' ) Are your sure about your selectors ?

Comment: `new Date()` expects it as `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: @JohanWillfred you are right I've corrected the code now.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can generate date as `new Date(year,month,day)` you need to construct your date this way then try this,

```
var date = new Date(2010,10,10)
(new Date().getTime() - date.getTime())/ (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

In this code, I am subtracting the date from current date, with little modification you can get it worked for your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the date format with a placeholder. If the browser supports date well it will be overridden depending on local settings, in which case the actual field value should always be in YYYY-MM-DD format. This is how Chrome handles the field.

In this case it will work

```
var from = new Date($("#from").val());
var to = new Date($("#to").val());
if (from > to)
```

Other browsers like Firefox for instance do however not support the date field well. It will just work like a normal text input. In this case you will need to do some string manipulation to separate the values and insert them in a way that Date() expects:
new Date(YYYY, MM, DD);